# 送信に特化したメール送信ライブラリ

Tags: java

依存が少なく（単体で動く）メール送信ライブラリはありますか？
JavaMailなどではなく、通知用なのでとにかく送信だけのシンプルなものがいいです。
（メールサーバーを作らない、経由しない）
CentOSでの`sendmail`コマンドのようなものが理想です。

Comment: JavaMailだとどんな問題があるのか追記してもらえると回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: JavaMailだと、ライブラリが大きすぎる点と、
他のライブラリ（ログ出力とか）に依存していた気がするので送信だけに特化したものがあればと思いました。

Comment: Java6以降ではactivation.jarは必要なくなったので、JavaMailはjavax.mail.jarファイルのみで大丈夫だと思います。あとはjavax.mail.jarファイルの大きさが589KBなので、これが大きいかどうかという感じでしょうか。これは全部入りなので、SMTP実装のみのjarであればもう少し小さくなるはずです。JavaMail以外だと、ちょっと検索しただけでは見当たらないですね。

Comment: 600kは大きいですね…20k以下がいいなとも思いましたが、仕方ないのかもしれないですね。。。
http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/587689.html
みたいに本当にシンプルなものないかな…

Comment: ないなら作ってみますか！！！！

Comment: どこまで機能を削るかは決めていますか？例えば、日本語などの他バイトコードを扱うか否かで、コードの複雑さは相当変わります。　メールサーバは無いとなると、受信をする各サイトに受信箱を設けないといけなくなりますが、それって想定しているシステムに適していますか？

Answer (score 1):

Java で SMTP を扱うという観点なら [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) もあります。

FTP や NNTP などのプロトコルも含まれていますので、jar は小さくはないですが。